# How to convert matrix in console of Scilab to latex in a short cut way?

Tags: latex, scilab

Actually, I have a big matrix in the console of Scilab. It is very tedious to type this matrix in the TeXt file of latex. My aim is to write latex code for this matrix automatically in the text file. Can anybody help me?
[ I have the big matrix like this A=[0.2  0.3  0.3;  0.4  0.5  0.6;  0.7  0.8  0.9] in the console].  (big in the sense that row runs about 30 and column runs about 6).

Comment: SO is a Q&A website, especially about programming. Without any code in your question, you aren't following the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask) . You should at least show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then we will help you. 

Considering your problem, i would suggest to take a look at the `mprintf` function.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have the matrix like this A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks information about the inputed matrix : real, complex, integer valued ? And how do you want the output : floating, exponential ?

Since your problem is rather simple and understable, here is an answer that will assume a real matrix:

```
function display_as_pmatrix(A,fmt)
  if ~exists('fmt') then // default format : 10-th wide exponential notation with 3 digit
    fmt='%10.3e'
  end
  // writing a latex pmatrix 
  // & between each term
  // \\ a the end of each row
  // except on the last row
  mprintf('\\begin{pmatrix}\n') // mprintf accept C-printf 
  for j=1:size(A,1)-1
    mprintf(fmt,A(j,1).')
    mprintf(' \& '+fmt,A(j,2:$).')
    mprintf('\\\\\n')
  end
  j=size(A,1)
  mprintf(fmt,A(j,1).')
  mprintf(' \& '+fmt,A(j,2:$).')
  mprintf('\n\\end{pmatrix}\n')
endfunction
```

This function is used like this

```
-->display_as_pmatrix(A,'%10.3e')
\begin{pmatrix}
 2.360e-01 &  8.837e-01 &  2.262e-02\\
 4.076e-01 &  2.393e-01 &  8.311e-01\\
 7.294e-01 &  9.087e-01 &  4.105e-01
\end{pmatrix}

-->display_as_pmatrix(A,'%5.2g')
\begin{pmatrix}
 0.24 &  0.88 & 0.23\\
 0.41 &  0.24 &  0.83\\
 0.73 &  0.91 &  0.41
\end{pmatrix}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very useful. I have the matrix like this A=[0.2  0.3  0.3;  0.4  0.5  0.6;  0.7  0.8  0.9] in the console. This is the sample, but actually, I have the big real matrix

Comment: Dear PTRK, your answer is very helpful, I got my solution. It works well and perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use native function `prettyprint`:

```
--> z = rand(4,4);
--> prettyprint(z)
 ans  =

 ${\begin{pmatrix}0.6733739&0.1899375&0.0403497&0.2514597\cr 0.6536 
 925&0.2583981&0.7400147&0.3843350\cr 0.1996896&0.0987874&0.6162660 
 &0.4396460\cr 0.6014125&0.0619903&0.6583583&0.6540737\cr \end{pmat 
 rix}}$
```

The result is a bit messy, but you can copy and paste it with minimum edition in a TeX file. For example, I had to delete the line break in the keyword `pmatrix`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

 ${\begin{pmatrix}0.6733739&0.1899375&0.0403497&0.2514597\cr 0.6536 
 925&0.2583981&0.7400147&0.3843350\cr 0.1996896&0.0987874&0.6162660 
 &0.4396460\cr 0.6014125&0.0619903&0.6583583&0.6540737\cr \end{pmatrix}}$

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Minimum TeX output]

If your matrix have more than 10 columns, you need to add `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{ncols}` to the preamble, where `ncols` is greater than the number of columns.